# Delete Slow Query Log File

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, performance, slow-log

I was logging slow queries of my system. Now I have few queries to be optimized and reset the global `slow_query_log` variable to `0`. Now I want to delete slow query log file `mysqld-slow.log`. can anyone tell me what is the standard way to do this ?

I am using Cent OS and do not want to delete or affect other log files (i.e. general log or binary log)
Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of 5.5.3, `FLUSH LOGS` will close and reopen the slowlog.  (In old versions, `FLUSH` had no effect on the slowlog.)

So, on *nix OS, this *should* work without restarting the server:

1. `rm` (to delete) or `mv` the slowlog to another name.  (Note: mysqld will continue to write to the file, even though you changed the name.)
2. `FLUSH LOGS;`.  As of 5.5.3, you can limit the effect via `FLUSH SLOW LOGS;`

See http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=14104 and http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=60878

I would not turn off the slowlog -- next month someone will add a naughty query and you will want to know about it.

Answer (score 3):

or set

```
SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 'OFF';
```

then clear the file and then

```
SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 'ON';
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple. If you want the slow query log file just take the backup and do below.

```
tail -n slow-query.log > slow-query.log
```

The above file will recreate with 'n' number of line with same name which clears the space.

Comment: Is this safe while the mysql service running?

Answer (score 0):

Let me tell you, how I did that.

1. **Stop** the **mysql service**.
2. **Backup / Copy** the existing slow query log to another directory or folder.
3. **Remove / Move** the log file to another directory.
4. Create a **new log file** with the same name.
5. **Start** **the mysql service**.

**Note:**

1. Make sure, you have **rights to move/remove** the log file.
2. You cannot delete the file, when **mysql service is accessing** the log file.

This worked for me, I hope it will help you too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using AWS RDS service, trying to

```
>truncate mysql.slow_log;

Error Code: 1044. Access denied for user 'rds_admin'@'%' to database 'mysql'
```

The RDS way to do this, is to call built-in function which will move slow_log table to slow

```
CALL mysql.rds_rotate_slow_log;
```